# What is the plastic barrier surrounding this choke for?

Tags: power-supply, shielding

I disassembled the mains power supply from an audio mixing desk. Immediately after the switch and inrush protection NTC is an [Epcos B82722 10mH / 1A choke](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/30/db/ind_2008/b82722a_j.pdf) (the blue component in the photo below).

The choke is surrounded by something wrapped in white plastic, which is held to the board with a cable tie.

[image: Photo of a power supply circuit board]

I assume this is some form of shielding, designed to minimise any effects from the magnetic field on the adjacent switching circuit.

Is this assumption correct? What are these shields typically made of? I am trying to repair the power supply so would rather not remove it from the board to find out.

Comment: Might be some sort of mu-metal for magnetic field shielding

Comment: Really odd! Can you take it apart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally it is very thin CRGOS transformer steel insulated with more plastic.  This is designed to absorb differential current noise radiate to near by magnetics and outside the box.  e.g.the  yellow taped choke which appears to be an additional CM choke to the silver common mode choke. This provides better noise reduction for RF from the SMPS and also added to improve lightning strike immunity.

The common mode coupling to nearby and radiated emissions is a common  problem and this appears to be an added differential choke for ingress/egress.

Comment: Is that the equivalent of those copper coils you see around capacitors sometimes?

Comment: The yellow component is a transformer (XFRMR E/30/15/7A (UNI) (AM5547)) between the high voltage and low voltage sides.

Comment: TY @David. That also provides CM isolation